Css animation in ios devices
I added this custom html, css and js in my website. It's an hamburger menu with animation which i have to insert in my website.
The transformation works in android devices, not in ios ones.
What can i do to fix it?
I tried to insert webkit prefix in each part of css part but nothing happens.
Code Snippet


var state = 0;
var icona = document.getElementById("icon");
var path = document.getElementById("mypath");

icona.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  if (state == 0) {
    path.classList.remove('shape2');
    path.classList.add('shape1');
    state = 1;
    console.log("shape1");
  } else {
    path.classList.remove('shape1');
    path.classList.add('shape2');
    state = 0;
    console.log("shape2");
  }
});


icona.addEventListener("touchstart", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  if (state == 0) {
    path.classList.remove('shape2');
    path.classList.add('shape1');
    state = 1;
    console.log("shape1");
  } else {
    path.classList.remove('shape1');
    path.classList.add('shape2');
    state = 0;
    console.log("shape2");
  }
});
body {
  background-color: black;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.shape1 {
  -webkit-animation: webkit-apertura 800ms ease-in-out forwards;
  animation: apertura 800ms ease-in-out forwards;
}

.shape2 {
  -webkit-animation: webkit-chiusura 800ms ease-in-out forwards;
  animation: chiusura 800ms ease-in-out forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes webkit-apertura {
  0% {
    d: path("M 1 1 L 16 1 M 16 1 L 31 1 M 1 11 L 16 11 M 16 11 L 31 11 M 1 21 L 16 21 M 16 21 L 31 21");
  }
  50% {
    d: path("M 1 11 L 16 1 M 16 1 L 31 11 M 1 11 L 16 11 M 16 11 L 31 11 M 1 11 L 16 21 M 16 21 L 31 11");
  }
  100% {
    d: path("M 16 11 L 6 1 M 26 1 L 16 11 M 16 11 L 16 11 M 16 11 L 16 11 M 16 11 L 6 21 M 26 21 L 16 11");
  }
}

@keyframes apertura {
  0% {
    d: path("M 1 1 L 16 1 M 16 1 L 31 1 M 1 11 L 16 11 M 16 11 L 31 11 M 1 21 L 16 21 M 16 21 L 31 21");
  }
  50% {
    d: path("M 1 11 L 16 1 M 16 1 L 31 11 M 1 11 L 16 11 M 16 11 L 31 11 M 1 11 L 16 21 M 16 21 L 31 11");
  }
  100% {
    d: path("M 16 11 L 6 1 M 26 1 L 16 11 M 16 11 L 16 11 M 16 11 L 16 11 M 16 11 L 6 21 M 26 21 L 16 11");
  }
}

@keyframes chiusura {
  0% {
    d: path("M 16 11 L 6 1 M 26 1 L 16 11 M 16 11 L 16 11 M 16 11 L 16 11 M 16 11 L 6 21 M 26 21 L 16 11");
  }
  50% {
    d: path("M 1 11 L 16 1 M 16 1 L 31 11 M 1 11 L 16 11 M 16 11 L 31 11 M 1 11 L 16 21 M 16 21 L 31 11");
  }
  100% {
    d: path("M 1 1 L 16 1 M 16 1 L 31 1 M 1 11 L 16 11 M 16 11 L 31 11 M 1 21 L 16 21 M 16 21 L 31 21");
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes webkit-chiusura {
  0% {
    d: path("M 16 11 L 6 1 M 26 1 L 16 11 M 16 11 L 16 11 M 16 11 L 16 11 M 16 11 L 6 21 M 26 21 L 16 11");
  }
  50% {
    d: path("M 1 11 L 16 1 M 16 1 L 31 11 M 1 11 L 16 11 M 16 11 L 31 11 M 1 11 L 16 21 M 16 21 L 31 11");
  }
  100% {
    d: path("M 1 1 L 16 1 M 16 1 L 31 1 M 1 11 L 16 11 M 16 11 L 31 11 M 1 21 L 16 21 M 16 21 L 31 21");
  }
}
<div style="color:white">touch or click to animate</div>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 40 20" id="icon">
    <path id="mypath" d="M 1 1 L 16 1 M 16 1 L 31 1 M 1 11 L 16 11 M 16 11 L 31 11 M 1 21 L 16 21 M 16 21 L 31 21" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="1" />
</svg>




Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question.

Safari doesn't support CSS d property see https://caniuse.com/?search=d

Have a look at this Owen Shepard's codepen example based on SMIL animation

As commented by A Haworth safari still lacks support for the svg <path> related d property.
Fortunately you can combine svg SMIL animation with a simple javascript function to start and reverse the path animation:


initNavToogle(navicon);

function initNavToogle(navicon) {
  let aniNav = navicon.getElementById("aniNav");
  
  // get path data values
  let valueArr = aniNav
    .getAttribute("values")
    .split(";")
    .map((val) => {
      return val.trim();
    });

  navicon.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    //toggle state
   navicon.classList.toggle("active");

    // start animation
    aniNav.beginElement();
  });
  
    //reverse path data values
    aniNav.addEventListener("endEvent", (e) => {
      aniNav.setAttribute("values", valueArr.reverse().join(";"));
    });
}
body {
  background: #000;
}

svg{
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding:10px;
  width:15vmin;
}
<svg id="navicon" class="navicon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 22" stroke-width="2" stroke="#fff" fill="none" style="cursor: pointer">
  <path id="navicon_path" d="m1 1 15 0m0 0 15 0m-30 10 15 0m0 0 15 0m-30 10 15 0m0 0 15 0"  />
  <animate href="#navicon_path"
           id="aniNav"
           dur="0.8s" 
           attributeName="d" 
           values="m1 1 15 0m0 0 15 0m-30 10 15 0m0 0 15 0m-30 10 15 0m0 0 15 0;
                   m1 11 15-10m0 0 15 10m-30 0 15 0m0 0 15 0m-30 0 15 10m0 0 15-10;
                   m16 11-10-10m20 0-10 10m0 0 0 0m0 0 0 0m0 0-10 10m20 0-10-10" 
           fill="freeze" 
           keyTimes="0;0.25;1"
           calcMode="spline"
               keySplines="0.42 0 0.58 1;
                       0.42 0 0.58 1"
           begin="indefinite"
           />
</svg>



Specify the animation states in the values attribute by adding all d path data strings separated by asemicolon:
values="m1 1 15 0m0 0 15 0m-30 10 15 0m0 0 15 0m-30 10 15 0m0 0 15 0;
m1 11 15-10m0 0 15 10m-30 0 15 0m0 0 15 0m-30 0 15 10m0 0 15-10;
m16 11-10-10m20 0-10 10m0 0 0 0m0 0 0 0m0 0-10 10m20 0-10-10" 

begin="indefinite" will prevent the animation to start immediately as we want to start it only on click.
Unfortunately SMIL doesn't support keyword based easing function. But you can get similar results as in CSS by adjusting keyTimes and keySplines. See also "How do you add easing to an SVG SMIL animation?"
When the navicon is clicked we start the animation via animationElement.beginElement() method.
Once the animation reached its end we reverse the path data array:
aniNav.addEventListener("endEvent", (e) => {
   aniNav.setAttribute("values", valueArr.reverse().join(";"));
});

Further reading

A Guide to SVG Animations (SMIL)
SMIL only codepen example by Owen Shepard

